# How to replace a word in an exisiting text file in java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader, ioexception

I want to replace a word to another word in an existing text file. I think my code is correct but whenever **I run the program all the text gets deleted in the text file.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException{

         String getText, putText;
         File f = new File("Test.txt");
         FileReader fr ;
         BufferedReader br ;
         BufferedWriter bw;
         if(f.exists()){
             try{
                 fr = new FileReader(f);
                 br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                 bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
                 while((getText = br.readLine()) != null){
                     System.out.println(getText);
                     if(getText != null){
                         putText = getText.replaceFirst("Dog", "Cat");
                         bw.write(putText);
                     }   
                 }
                bw.close();
                br.close();
             }
             catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }else{
             System.out.println("No File exists!");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You write over the same file as you read it... So yeah, anyways `if(getText != null){` will always be true according to the while loop

Comment: yet puText is the same as getText beside dog gets replaced, therefore it should still work. is the question where exactly bw is writing. is it writing to first empty line or where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply should not read and write from/to **the same** file at the same point in time.

Instead: read from file *A*; and write to some file *A.tmp*.

And if you absolutely want to, you can still delete *A*, and rename *A.tmp* to *A* in the end.

Finally, just for the record: if your goal is really just that; to replace some strings in some text file, the more reasonable answer would be to look into tools such [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) (or some alternatives that exist for Windows OSes).

To replace only the **first** occurance of some string, you have to add some *marker* that tells you if you replaced already, like:

```
boolean replacingRequired = true;
while ( ... reading ...) 
  if (replacingRequired) {
     putText = getText.replaceFirst("Dog", "Cat")
     if (! putText.equals(getText)) {
       // when they are different, you replaced something!
       replacingRequired = false;
     }
  ...
```

Final finally: as you are now asking about replacing the **last** occurance ... well, that is a completely different and **harder** problem.  You see, your current approach is to read that input file line by line, update that line, and write that to the new file. But: how could code that goes line-by-line know that **this** line ... is the last one that carries the pattern that you wish to replace?! Short answer: it can't.

The simply solution here; which works nicely unless your files are really big:

1. Read **all** lines into a List of strings (using this [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) for example)
2. Then walk **backwards** through that list; and replace the first occurrence (which when walking backwards is the **last** one !) within that list
3. Write the **updated** list into your file

Comment: I want the same file name. Is it possible that I create a temporary file and delete the exisiting file and rename the temp file to exisiting file ?

Comment: It worked!! I want to ask one more question which is that I want to just change the first occurrence of "Dog", but rather all the "Dog" changes to "Cat" because there are 4 lines so each time the loop works it replaces.

So it there any way I can just change the first occurrence of "Dog" only ?

Comment: I added *some* code to get you going. Of course, you have to make sure to add that in a reasonable manner to your existing code.

Comment: I was trying for last occurrence of "Dog", I made a method for it [link](http://pastebin.com/WDxY7Ks2) but the problem is it acts as replaceFirst only.

But if I try to start from end then last lines will be printed first, so that also does not works. How I can resolve this ?

Comment: I put another update into my answer. But please understand that this is **not** how SO is supposed to work. We dont sit down with you and hold hands and guide you through each step of your homework. Especially, you shouldnt come back and ask more questions on an answer that solves your original question. And seriously: if you want to learn to program, than you should be doing such things ... more on your own. One core aspect of learning is to ask yourself "how could i do that" ... as long as it takes. Avoid the "lets ask others" detour!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128184/discussion-between-topper1309-and-ghostcat).

Answer (score 0):

You should try and duplicate your file instead of reading and writing in the same file

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
      ....
     StringBuilder fullText =new StringBuilder();
      while((getText = br.readLine()) != null){
            putText = ""; 
            if(getText != null){
                putText = getText.replaceFirst("Dog", "Cat"); 
            }   
            fullText.append(putText);
        } 
    br.close();
    bw.write(putText);
    bw.close()
```